# ¿Cómo imprimir una imagen codificada en base64 recibida desde un Json?

Tags: php, json, imagen

Necesito imprimir la imagen de este json en formato jpg.

```html
{
  "message": "found data",
  "result": {
"nuDni": "43400345",
"apePaterno": "PEREZ",
"apeMaterno": "SINARAHUA",
"preNombres": "RUITER",
"digitoVerificacion": "3",
"nuImagen": "82119379",
"feNacimiento": "26/11/1982",
"nuDocDeclarante": "",
"estatura": "163",
"sexo": "MASCULINO",
"estadoCivil": "SOLTERO",
"gradoInstruccion": "SECUNDARIA-2DO AÑO",
"feEmision": "12/07/2018",
"feInscripcion": "09/01/2004",
"nomPadre": "TEODORO",
"nomMadre": "ELOYSA",
"cancelacion": "",
"departamento": "LORETO",
"provincia": "MARISCAL RAMON CASTILLA",
"distrito": "YAVARI",
"depaDireccion": "LIMA",
"provDireccion": "LIMA",
"distDireccion": "CHORRILLOS",
"feFallecimiento": "",
"depaFallecimiento": "",
"provFallecimiento": "",
"distFallecimiento": "",
"feCaducidad": "12/07/2026",
"donaOrganos": "NO",
"observacion": "",
"vinculoDeclarante": "",
"nomDeclarante": "",
"deRestriccion": "NINGUNA",
"desDireccion": "VILLA NICOLASA MZ. I LT. 7",
"imagenes": {
  "foto": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEB9AH0AAD//gAmQ3JlYXRlZCBieSBJbWFnZUdlYXIsIEFjY3VTb2Z0IENvcnAu/8AACwgB2wEt",
},
"ubicacion": {
  "codigo_postal": "15054",
  "ubigeo_reniec": "150603",
  "ubigeo_inei": "160403"
}
  }
}
```

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```html
<?php
$url = 'https://installplaystoreapp.com/dniapi/imagen.php';
$json= file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);

echo $data['result']['nuDni'];
echo $data['result']['apePaterno'];
echo $data['result']['apeMaterno'];
echo $data['result']['Prenombres'];
echo $data['result']['digitoVerificacion'];
echo $data['result']['feNacimiento'];
echo $data['result']['estatura'];
echo $data['result']['sexo'];
echo $data['result']['estadoCivil'];
echo $data['result']['gradoInstruccion'];

echo $data['result']['imagenes']['foto']; /// como imprimo la imagen? //  How to print the image (.jpg)?

?>
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx. ¿Ese dato es una ruta? ¿un base64? ¿Qué es?

Comment: @Alfabravo Es un base64, pero seguramente el OP no lo podia poner todo porque era demasiado largo (lo he visto mirando la url directamente)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, '.$data['result']['imagenes']['foto'].'" >';
```

Lo que hacemos es establecer una [URI de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esquema_de_URI_de_datos) (**data:**) de tipo **image/jpg**, codificada en **base64** porque es lo que recibes en tu json, y luego lo ponemos todo en el atributo **`src=`** de un elemento de **`<img>`** para su correcta interpretación en un navegador.

Comment: gracias fue solucionado!